# Shortcut to enter the Exception Assistant (exception window) while debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio debugging, when an exception occurs, the [Exception Assistant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/23/the-exception-assistant-vstipdebug0030.aspx) shows without being in focus. What is the shortcut to set focus to it? I have tried `Ctrl` + `Tab` without luck.

In other words, I want to be able to *View Detail...*, *Enable editing*, *Copy exception detail to the clipboard*, and *Open exception settings*, which are **Actions** available from the exception window.

[image: How do we enter this exception window?]

Comment: I don't think there is one, it was made for mousing.  Perhaps is time to turn it off, Tools + Options, Debugging, General.  The Locals window now automatically displays the `$exception` pseudo variable.

Comment: @HansPassant Good call. Done. The local window with `$exception` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Hit {Escape} to close the dialog then hit CTRL + . (Control-Dot) to re-open it

(the window should have had focus when it first popped up, so this solution might not work for you)